# Arbitrary choice of antecedent and consequent/

Tags: logic

Here there are two statements with different meaning. The first one is: (if A then B) and A, then this implies B is a logical truth and the second one (if A then B) and B, then this doesn't implies A. But what if I circumvent the second constraint, by constraint I meant the logical untruth, by exchanging B with A only in limited way so as to make the statement valid. For example, (if it rains, then it turns green) and it rains then that implies it turns green, is logical valid statement. But (if it rains, then it turns green) and it turns green, then that implies it rains is not logically true, right. But what if I put "it turns green" instead of "it rains" in the statement between parenthesis, then the statement becomes true. This means there is arbitrariness in choosing which context to put in order to make the whole statement valid which means there is always a way to make the second statement always true by assigning which context to be the antecedent and which is consequent without looking at the causality of which causes which. Is this true? Does causality play a role in the implication (if, then)? and if it does, can we circumvent this logical invalidity I mentioned by playing with language and orders?

Comment: You write: "... and which is consequent without looking at the causality of which causes which." We never look at any kind of causality. **Implication is not causation**. $A \to B$ means exactly "true iff $A$ is false or $B$ is true"; this has nothing to do with causality. See also [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1932533/344246).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $A \to B$ means something different from $B \to A$. That is perfectly fine; there is no reason to assume they should mean the same thing, or have the same function. This is only "arbitrary" in the sense that we need to write the arguments $A,B$ in *some* order, and this is the one we usually choose.